# Does Angular creates a singleton class or a new class when a component is revisited

Tags: angular

Say my Angular application has two components, `A` and `B`. The HTML of both `A` and `B` has some text fields. `A` has a link to `B` and vice versa.

I am on `A`, I enter some data in the text field and then I go to `B`. Then I come back to `A` from B by clicking the link to `A` in `B` (not by back button). Would the data I entered initially in `A` still be there?

I am trying to understand if a new instance of a component is created when it is visited.

Comment: Can you supply some sample code?

Comment: Angular manages the life-cycle of a component. So when the component is added or remove the life-cycle hooks are executed. As long as `A exists the data remains, but if it is removed from the DOM the data is lost. Unless `A` does something to make it persist. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Thanks Reactgular (like the name!). I suppose a component gets removed from DOM if I am routing to a new component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, you're asking

> when a component gets destroyed, does the state of the component (i.e. it's properties) remain

The answer is no.

in your scenario, if you

1. go from Comp A to Comp B
2. enter data in an input field in comp B
3. Go back to Comp A
4. then finally return to Comp B

the data you entered in step 2 will not be there.

Without seeing your code, I can only assume that your mention of 'links' means your going between components using the router. if that is the case then using the router to pass parameters around is a good use case https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters

If instead your components are on the same page, have a parent/child relationship you may want to consider reviewing https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction